# How to check if address lists exist in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to check if All Global Address Lists, All Address List and All System Address Lists exist in Active Directory before get all item from them.

Could you give me some advices or article that I can solve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you talking about ? what is that address & address list. your question leading nowhere. please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry Palak, have you ever heard about Active Directory? @@

Comment: its AD, i got it your question is regarding, but my concern was not AD at all.

Answer (score 1):

Address Lists are part of Exchange functionality not Active Directory which is what I think people are confused about.

Anyway, Address List data is stored in the Active Directory Configuration context under:

`CN=Address Lists Container,CN=<EXCHANGE ORGANIZATION NAME>,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=<DEFAULT NAMING CONTEXT>`

You can use ADSIEdit to view the information.

In C# you can use an LDAP query to retrieve information for existing Address Lists.

Edit: Something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
DirectoryEntry configContainer = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + rootDSE.Properties["configurationNamingContext"].Value);
DirectorySearcher configSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(configContainer);
configSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=addressBookContainer))";
configSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
configSearcher.PageSize = 10000;
configSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
SearchResultCollection results = configSearcher.FindAll();
```

Comment: Thank you for your commentary. But, i need to check if it exists in AD, or not.

Comment: @PhucNguyen You need to explain yourself better because this DOES check if an Address List exists in AD.